# Customize a third party gem and use it in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am using a gem that I customized for my app (using Rails 5.0). I modified just a few lines of code to get it to do what I need and it works fine in my local environment. But how do I change the gem code in production? There is the vendor directory in Rails projects and a 5+ year old SO advice was to put it in the no longer existing vendor/gems directory. Should I put it in the vendor directory? Make a vendor/gems directory and put it there? And if I do how do I tell Rails to look there?

Changing the official gem itself is something I may try to do as well but in the short term I just want to make sure I can use the customized gem in production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell your Gemfile where to look for your gem. You can just download it from github or use `gem unpack` to extract it from wherever system ruby or bundler has it installed.

```
gem 'mygem', path: "vendor/gems/mygem"
```

Or your own git repo:

```
gem 'mygem', :git => "https://github.com/you/mygem.git"
```

or monkeypatch the method that you changed.

Comment: Do I just download the gem from github and put it in the vendor folder and add the path in the gemfile or is there more I need to do?

Comment: yep. you can also use cd vendor/gems; gem unpack mygem

Comment: Worked! Too easy. Thanks.